# Help identifying shrub, long narrow leaves, white flowers

Tags: identification, shrubs

Can anyone help me identify this bush, shown in the photos? It is growing happily in our garden in the UK. We are coastal, and rarely get a frost.

We planted it 6 years ago when it was about half the size of a football, it is now about 10ft across.

It is a spherical shrub, evergreen, with long narrow leaves growing in pairs. The flower had is made up of lots of tiny white flowers, as shown in the photos. It is just starting to flower now in July.

Any help greatly appreciated.

[image: The whole shrub]

[image: Flowers 1]

[image: Flowers 2]

[image: Leaves]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Hebe variety, maybe H. tairawhiti, which can get 3 metres high, so it's the right sort of size, but in its native New Zealand, where it grows well in coastal regions, it flowers white in spring. Its leaves have a yellowish midrib, see image here http://www.terrain.net.nz/friends-of-te-henui-group/hebes/hebe-tairawhiti-wairoa-koromiko.html

The other possibility is Hebe 'snowdrift', but that usually only reaches 1.5 metres at maturity and has olive green leaves.